# how to change the background color in accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in javascript and try to make accordion with jquery but it seems it change the background color of the div and no matter what is the setting of the background color in the css the accordion doesn't seems to respond.

here is the html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>dreampage    </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">    </script>

</head>

<body>


<div class="newsbackground">


<div class="newsfeed">
```

here is the div that I manipulate to become accordion

```
<div class="fake_background_post">
<h1 class="poster">
<p class="post_text">Share your feeling to us!     </p>
</h1>


</div>

<div class="post_panel">
<form action="index.php" method="get" name="post">

<img class="upload_video_and_picture" src="./img/logo/camera.png" />
<p class="upload_video_and_picture_post_text">    <b>Upload Pictures or Video    </b>    </p>

<textarea placeholder="say something!!!" class="post_content" name="post_content" cols="60%" >     </textarea>



<div class="feeling">
<p class="feeling_text">FEELING!!!    </p>
<div class="feeling_logo">
<img class="happy" src="./img/logo/happy-ticon.png" />
<img class="excited" src="./img/logo/excited.png" />
<img class="sad" src="./img/logo/sad-ticon.png" />
<img class="mad" src="./img/logo/mad-ticon.png" />
<img class="bored" src="./img/logo/bored-ticon.png" />
</div>
</form>

</div>

</div>

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

$(".post").accordion ({
animate: 1500,
active: 1,
coolapsible: true,
event: "click",
heightstyle: "content",
}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the css code

```
* {margin: 0px;    
padding; 0px;    

font-family:comic sans ms;    


}    


.post_content {    
    border: 1px solid #472b1d;
     background-color: #ebe7db;
     color: #472b1d;
     width: 99%;
}    


.post_panel {    
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left:  0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 87.5%;
     background-color: #d2c195;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
}    


.post_panel img {    
    position:relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;


}    
.upload_video_and_picture {    
    position:relative;
    top: 8px;
    left: 10px;

}    
.upload_video_and_picture_post_text {    
    position:relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50px;
}    
.feeling {    
    position:relative;
    top: 8px;
    left: 10px;

}    

.feeling img {    
    position:relative;
    top: -21px;
    left:100px;

}    
    this is the the css code where the background color doesn't seems to respond
.post {    
position: relative;    
    top: 20px;
    left:  220px;

    padding-bottom: -200px;
     margin-bottom: 120px;
    width: 48%;


     background-color: #d2c195;

}    


.post > .fake_background_post {    


     background-color: #d2c195;

}    


.post_text {    
position: relative;    
    top: -23px;
    left:  110px;
    font-size: 70%;



     # background-color: #d2c195;

}    

.fake_background_post {    
    position: relative;
width: 100%;    
height: 70px;    
height: 33px;    
    left: 0px;
    top: 00px;
     background-color: #d2c195;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    border: 2px solid #472b1d;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition:  0.5s;
}    

.fake_background_post:hover {    

    background-color: #472b1d;
    color: #d2c195;

}
```

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to do  jsfiddle

Comment: @GodwinRomero, https://jsfiddle.net/ create your account, click on the editor and upload your code. then share the link with us

Comment: @Dolatabadi While fiddle may be used to test your code, the code snippet feature provided in SO should be used over fiddle in your question and answers. You can add the fiddle link, but that should be secondary

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/user/godwin2921/fiddles/ here is the fiddle tho.. I did'nt know the setting in javascript I tried my best to do it hope it will help a lot thanks

Comment: @Dolatabadi Seems like you misunderstood what I said and have no idea about stack snippets. Read this https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ for more info. Also I expect you to do the same in the future too.